# saving holoviews scatter plot visualizations in html

Tags: holoviews

```
####################
   :Layout
      .HoloMap.I  :HoloMap   [data_type,window_type,cell]
         :Scatter   [instance]   (irDrop)
      .Scatter.I  :Scatter   [cell]   (irDrop)
      .Scatter.II :Scatter   [cell]   (irDrop)
###################
```

trying to save the above layout using the following renderer methods

```
   renderer = hv.renderer('bokeh')
   renderer.save(myview, 'view.html')
```

The saving part is stuck forever. When i stop the jupyter kernel , i see the following stack trace. Any ideas what could be going on here.

Thanks

```
     14 
     15 def decode(input, errors='strict'):
---> 16     return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
     17 
     18 class IncrementalEncoder(codecs.IncrementalEncoder):
```

KeyboardInterrupt:

Comment: A bug report like this should be filed at the [HoloViews github repository](https://github.com/ioam/holoviews/issues), where we can get details about how to reproduce it and can close it when it's been addressed.

Comment: Thanks James. Yes would followup on GitHub.